# Can not access the virtual table

Tags: dataverse

I have grant all the permission from the origination level to a security role for a virtual table in Dataverse, but they still can not access the table, any one have any idea what is the potential reason?

Comment: Can you provide some more specifics on what happens when they try to access the virtual table, i.e., what is the error message? Which provider are you using? Can other uses access the table? Specifically can a system administrator user access the table successfully?